# In Windows store app, the types 'XmlNode' and 'XmlElement ' does not exist

Tags: c#, windows-8.1

While developing *Windows store app*, I got to know that the types 'System.Xml.XmlNode' and 'System.Xml.XmlElement ' does not exist. 
Following code is giving error.

```
public static XmlElement GetElement(XmlElement parent, string elementName, string namespaceURI)
        {
            foreach (XmlNode x in parent.ChildNodes)
            {
                if (x.NodeType == XmlNodeType.Element && x.Name.Equals(elementName) && x.NamespaceURI.Equals(namespaceURI))
                    return (XmlElement)x;
            }

            return null;
        }
```

**Error**:

> The type or namespace name 'XmlElement' does not exist in the
>   namespace 'System.Xml' (are you missing an assembly reference?)

**Please let me know is there any replacement of these classes in *.NetCore*.**

Comment: what about using linq to xml?

Comment: @SonerGönül those classes aren't available in this api.

Comment: @soner: is there any need to add dll as it is automatically added win win store app? i am just using System.Xml;

Comment: @user3524034 i would suggest using linq to xml.

Comment: @DanielA.White: what is the possible solution? as I have to convert all my code of .net framework 4.5 to .netore.

Comment: XMLElement found in *Windows.Data.Xml.Dom* namespace. but problem persists for XMLNode.

Answer (score 0):

I would convert to using [Linq to XML which is described here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb387061.aspx).

It's not a perfect replacement for the DOM API, but it is supported on many platforms.

Comment: XMLElement found in Windows.Data.Xml.Dom namespace.